# Replace multiple characters in html, with only one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a script that replaces certain words with html tags:

```
$("body").children().each(function () {
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace("#stern","<b>"));
    });

$("body").children().each(function () {
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace('#$stern',"</b>") );
    });
```

And it works well, but I would like to merge the `#$stern` into the same function as the `#stern`, because it will load faster, and I would like to do the same with different tags, rather than tediously writing each one.

**Note:** (I know `<b>` is deprecated, it is just an example)

**Edit**
 It should also replace multiple `#stern` instead of one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the callback for `html` and run both replacements on the string from the arguments

```
$("body").children().html(function (_, html) {
    return html.replace(/\#stern/g,"<b>").replace(/\#\$stern/g,"</b>");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/4ccjry0u/1/)

That saves you like six function calls and two loops

Comment: This doesn't work when I try putting more than one `#stern` down

Comment: @ScriptKitty - no, you'll need a global modifier for that, edited the answer

Answer (score 3):

Use chaining of replace method:

```
$("body").children().each(function () {
 $(this).html( $(this).html().replace("#stern","<b>").replace('#$stern',"</b>"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following, instead of looping and replacing over each element inside `body`. This will be **Faster**.

```
var bodyHtml = $('body').html();
bodyHtml.replace(/#stern/i, "<b>").replace(/#\$stern/i, '</b>');
$('body').html(bodyHtml);
```

Alternately, You can use `regex`(**Slower**) inside `replace` as follow:

```
$("body").children().each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/#stern/i, "<b>").replace(/#\$stern/i, '</b>'));
});
```

1. `/`  : The delimiter of `regex`
2. `#`  : Matches `#`
3. `()` : Matching Group
4. `\$` : Matches `$`, should be escaped by `\`
5. `?`  : Matches zero or one of the preceding characters
6. `i`  : Case Insensitive match

Comment: Notice: `'#$stern'` is replaced by `"</b>"`